# mvc3 razor - url.action javascript error onClick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having a problem with my url.action and my javascript onClick event call. What I am trying to do is pass my controller and actionresult method as a parameter for my javascript but I keep getting an error of:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /UserManager/filterGrid

for this code:

```
<div class="webgrid-filter">

    <input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("filterGrid", "UserManager")')" id="chkboxGridFilter" />

</div>
```

**view**

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>


@*@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model
*@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Manager Dashboard";
}

    @Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "CreateUser")


<div class="webgrid-filter">

    <input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("filterGrid", "UserManager")')" id="chkboxGridFilter" />

</div>


<div class="webgrid-wrapper">



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jobs";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 15, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", fieldNamePrefix: "gridItem");

}

    @grid.GetHtml(
    fillEmptyRows: true,
        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
columns: new[] {
    grid.Column("UserName"),
    grid.Column("salutation"),
    grid.Column("FirstName"),
    grid.Column("LastName"),
    grid.Column("Password"),
    //grid.Column("isactive"),
    //grid.Column(header: "Is logged in?", format: (model) => @Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox' checked='" + ((model.isactive) ? "checked" : "unchecked") + "' />")),  
    grid.Column(header: "User logged in", format: @<text><input name="User logged in" 
      type="checkbox"  @(item.isactive == true ? "Checked" : null) onclick="logUserOff('@Url.Action("LogUserOff", "UserManager", new {userid = item.userid} )')" id="chkboxIsActive" /></text>),
    grid.Column("isApproved"),  
    grid.Column("MaxConcurrentUsers"),
    grid.Column("email"),
    grid.Column("group_name"),
   grid.Column("module_name"), 


     grid.Column(header:"Edit", format:@<text><div id="btnEditSelectedRow">
         "@Html.ActionLink("Edit record", "EditUser", "UserManager", new {
         userid = item.userid,
         salutation = item.salutation,
         firstname = item.FirstName, 
         lastname = item.LastName, 
         password = item.Password, 
         isactive = item.isactive,
         isapproved = item.IsApproved,
         maxconcurrentusers = item.MaxConcurrentUsers,
         email = item.email, 
         module = item.module_name, 
         group = item.group_name }, null)</div></text>),

    grid.Column(header:"Delete", format:@<text><div id="btnDelSelectedRow">
        "@Html.ActionLink("Delete record", "DeleteUser", "UserManager", new {
         userid = item.userid,
         username = item.UserName,
         salutation = item.salutation,
         firstname = item.FirstName, 
         lastname = item.LastName, 
         password = item.Password, 
         isactive = item.isactive, 
         email = item.email, 
         module = item.module_name, 
         group = item.group_name }, null)</div></text>)


})
</div><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Disable checkboxs where a user is not active.
        $(".webgrid-wrapper input:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Style tables.
        function jQueryUIStyling() {
            $('input:button, input:submit').button();

            $('.webgrid-wrapper').addClass('ui-grid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            $('.webgrid-title').addClass('ui-grid-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-top');
            jQueryTableStyling();
        } // end of jQueryUIStyling

        function jQueryTableStyling() {
            $('.webgrid').addClass('ui-grid-content ui-widget-content');
            $('.webgrid-header').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $('.webgrid-footer').addClass('ui-grid-footer ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix');
        } // end of jQueryTableStyling
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function logUserOff(url) {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to save this data?')
        if (answer) {
//            alert(url + ": " + value);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST"
//                data: value
            }).done(function () {
                $(this).addClass("done");
            });


            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function filterGrid(url) {
        alert($(url).val());
    }

</script>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function filterGrid(url) {
        alert($(url).val());
    }

</script>
```

Error originates from jquery-1.5.1:

```
throw"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+a
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check the page source and paste here what is being printed.

Comment: The error originates from my jquery script as well which is wierd because I am using url.helper somewhere else in a webgrid and it works.

Comment: @Diego the error is thrown in my jquery script for some reason.

Comment: why do you use `@Url.Action()` in the first place. You could pass them as a string i.e `filterGrid('/UserManager/filterGrid' );`

Comment: @the_ruby_racer: That is useful to keep consistence between the URLs in the site. Also, if the route changes that URL will be automatically corrected, which wont happen if you hardcode the URL.

Comment: @nickgowdy That may depend from the browser or when the javascript is executed. What the error is saying is that javascript is trying to understand /filterGrid/UserManager instead of using it as string. Please post the HTML of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error id caused the way you are showing the value of your URL in the alert.

You should write it like this

```
function filterGrid(url) {
    alert(url);
}
```